# How would I move these two elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meltzerj/5XzMZ/

I want to modify this html/css so that the "?" is on the same line as the "Top Songs" link. More specifically, I want it to be right next to the "Top Songs" text (to the right of it), inside of the highlighting when you hover over the links.

I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: The problem is in display:block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I picking you up wrong or is it as simple as moving the ? char into the anchor?

```
<a href="/videos" class="top_songs  chosen_home_option">Top Songs?</a>
```

Sorry if I am not getting it.

EDIT: Ok, its own element:

```
<li> <a style="float:left" href="/videos" class="top_songs  chosen_home_option">Top Songs <span style="">?</span></a>  </l
```

i>

or perhaps

```
<li> <div class="chosen_home_option"> <a href="/videos" class="top_songs">Top Songs</a> <span style="">?</span> </div></li>
```

and change the css

```
a.top_songs, a.upvoted_songs, a.feed_display, a.find_friends, li.notifications {

    padding-left:15px;
    margin-top:2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 15px;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Won't `<a href="/videos" class="top_songs  chosen_home_option">Top Songs<span>?</span></a>` work for you then?